# после установки arch linux! Minimal Bash-like line editing is suported

Tags: linux, администрирование, grub, archlinux

установил arch  рядом с виндой, всё сделал по инструкции https://pingvinus.ru/note/archlinux-install#partitioning-free но после извлечения загрузочной флешки и перезагрузки выводит Minimal Bash-like line editing is suported. и граб консоль на чёрном экране, в чём дело ?

Comment: А перед этой строчкой больше ничего не выводит? Обычно перед этой строчкой написано в чём дело

Comment: пишу полный текст вывода: Minimal Bash-like line editing is suported.For the first word, TAB lists posible device or file complations. grub>

Comment: @Gybernaty, скорей всего конфиг grub'а не корректный/не там лежит... просмотри, действительно ли всё сделал как описано в разделе «Установка загрузчика GRUB» с коррекцией на свою систему и начинай курить арч-вику...

Comment: всё точно по мануалу делал это точно!

Comment: Если железо поддерживает EFI, выкинь Grub вообще. И ещё, чтобы люди увидели ответ на комментарий, пиши @ nickname в начале комментария.

Comment: @Gybernaty Из текста сообщения видно, что его выдаёт grub. Значит до загрузки ОС дело ещё не дошло.  Раз grub предлагает Вам посмотреть список устройств (обязательно сделайте это!), то это означает, что загрузить ОС с того раздела, который Вы задали при установке невозможно.  Почему это так, дистанционно определить невозможно -  надо смотреть таблицу разделов, их состояние и т.д. Возможно, Вы неправильно указали диск для загрузки. Возможно - забыли пометить его как загрузочный, при установке ОС. Вариантов - много, увы... Начните с анализа таблицы разделов.

Comment: Какой нафиг pingvinus.ru? :) Ну у арча же великолепная вики, где обо всём рассказано по шагам, используйте её